# IEnumerable.Count() returns 0 after 2nd call

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing a unit test comparing a set of expected and actual values in an `IEnumerable`. When I compare the counts of both, they are equal. However, when I compare the counts a second time one of them returns a count of 0.

```
using StreamReader sr = new(filepath);
using CsvReader cr = new(sr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
IEnumerable<ExpectedT> expectedValues = cr.GetRecords<ExpectedT>();
IEnumerable<ActualT> actualValues = GetActual();

Assert.AreEqual(expectedValues.Count(), actualValues.Count(), "1st assert") //passes
Assert.AreEqual(expectedValues.Count(), actualValues.Count(), "2nd assert") //fails
//expectedValues.Count() returns 0; actualValues.Count() remains the same
```

There's a difference in how the values are retrieved. `expectedValues` is retrieved from a static csv file read by a `StreamReader`. `actualValues` is retrieved using a static method that uses the `new ActualT()` constructor to create the instances and then stores them in the `IEnumerable`.

I feel like the issue has something to do with the fact that `expectedValues` is retrieved from a `Stream` but am not sure exactly why it's happening.

When I convert the `IEnumerables` to a `List` using the `ToList()` method both asserts pass.

```
using StreamReader sr = new(filepath);
using CsvReader cr = new(sr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
List<ExpectedT> expectedValues = cr.GetRecords<ExpectedT>().ToList();
List<ActualT> actualValues = GetActual().ToList();

Assert.AreEqual(expectedValues.Count, actualValues.Count, "1st assert") //passes
Assert.AreEqual(expectedValues.Count, actualValues.Count, "2nd assert") //passes
```

However, I'm still curious why this issue only seems to be occurring only with `expectedValues` when it's kept as an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: It looks like you know both an answer (enumerable already read whole stream on the first iteration and there is nothing left to read afterwards) and how to solve it (by materializing the collection with `ToList`)... so I'm not sure what could help you - as result I picked a duplicate that deals with a bit more generalized case. It is quite possible that your question/lack of understanding is different - try to [edit] to clarify... You may also want to read through the results of https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+ienumerable+multiple+enumeration+warning

Comment: (BTW, really appreciate effort put into the question - seeing "but this very similar code behaved as expected" part is very welcome)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the duplicate and the link you provided in the comment are super helpful and are already taking me through some rabbit holes. `IEnumerable`s and `Stream`s both are a bit more finicky than I had previously thought, so I'll be reading up on both concepts. Thanks for the info!